# Configure WRT54G2 to use Internet Port

Tags: networking, router, internet

I currently use a WRT54G2 to extend my network to other place of my house connected by an ethernet cable. It is configured as gateway, with DHCP disable, and works fine. This allow me to connect 3 more devices (since I'm using one of the ports). But now I need to connect a 4th computer and I need one more port.

I know I could just add a switch or connect the new computer view WIFI, but I'd like to know if I can configure my router in such way that it uses the "Internet" port for the connection that comes from my DSL router.

The manual says that it is for use to connect a DSL or Cable modem, but I tried to connect my incoming connection to it, but when I do that, while my computers keep their lan connections they can't reach the DHCP server at the DSL router to get the IP's, it fails and the computers lost the internet connectivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm hoping you have dd-wrt on that router.  If not, go to [the dd-wrt website](http://dd-wrt.com), follow the instructions for this model exactly, and put it on there.

Then hop on your routers web interface (192.168.1.1 by default, mine is different below), then click on VLANs, and put the "W" port in the same VLAN as the other four ports as illustrated below.

The stock firmware doesn't allow this as far as I know, but it's been years since I've even acknowledged the existence of stock firmware on any WRTXXX router.

[image]

Comment: So... that's the cause I can't use the WAN port because it is on a different VLAN... well, I was hoping it was a configuration thing without having to hack the router with a 3rd party firmware... but Thank you very much

Comment: Your router will be more stable as a result so it's worth it imho.